# Using thmtools: numbering with asterisk

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I would like to repeat a theorem number with an added asterisk. That is, the original theorem is:

**Theorem 1.** Lorem ipsum...

And I would like the analogue theorem to be:

**Theorem 1*.** Lorem ipsum...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, 
  spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{mystyle}

\let\variant\relax

\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  name={Theorem~\variant{$^\ast$}},
  style=mystyle,
  numbered=no,
]{theorem*}

\newenvironment{rtheorem}[1]
  {\newcommand\variant{\ref{#1}}\begin{theorem*}}
  {\end{theorem*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
A test regular theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Euler's identity]
\label{thm:euler}
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Another test regular theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{rtheorem}{thm:euler}[Euler's identity revisited]
$e^{i\pi} = -1$
\end{rtheorem}

\begin{theorem}
Yet another test regular theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The central idea is to use the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism for a variation of a previously stated theorem. The "regular" theorems are produced using the `theorem` environment; a variation of a given theorem is produced using the `rtheorem` theorem which has as mandatory argument the string used to label the original theorem (both environments admit the default optional argument).

Comment: Using `\begin{rtheorem}{<label>}[<opt>]` would avoid the need of having different cases: just do `\newcommand{\variant}{\ref{#1}}{\begin{theorem*}` and `\begin{theorem*}` will take care of the optional argument.

Comment: With the hyperref package this has the downside of placing a hyperlink in the number produced with rtheorem. Is there a way around this?