# Using thmtools to add an asterisk to a theorem number: how to not add the link when hyperref is used

Tags: hyperref, thmtools

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154908/30481) gives a nice way to add an asterisk (or any other symbol really) to an equation number.

The method works very well. Unfortunately, if the hyperref package is used, the new number with the asterisk will appear to have an undesired hyperlink.

Here is a working example (taken from the answer linked above) of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, 
  spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{mystyle}

\let\variant\relax

\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  name={Theorem~\variant{$^\ast$}},
  style=mystyle,
  numbered=no,
]{theorem*}

\newenvironment{rtheorem}[1]
  {\newcommand\variant{\ref{#1}}\begin{theorem*}}
  {\end{theorem*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Euler's identity]
\label{thm:euler}
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\end{theorem}

\begin{rtheorem}{thm:euler}[Euler's identity revisited]
$e^{i\pi} = -1$
\end{rtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I remove the hyperlink on the modified reference?

Comment: Use `\ref*` in `\newcommand\variant{\ref{#1}}\begin{theorem*}`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @HarishKumar that's exactly what I wanted, thanks! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From hyperref manual:

[image]

So if you want to refer to some thing with correct counter but don't want that to be a hyper link, use `\ref*` instead of `\ref`. So you have to define:

```
\newenvironment{rtheorem}[1]
  {\newcommand\variant{\ref*{#1}}\begin{theorem*}}
  {\end{theorem*}}
```

Full code will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt,
  spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{mystyle}

\let\variant\relax

\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  name={Theorem~\variant{$^\ast$}},
  style=mystyle,
  numbered=no,
]{theorem*}

\newenvironment{rtheorem}[1]
  {\newcommand\variant{\ref*{#1}}\begin{theorem*}}
  {\end{theorem*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Euler's identity]
\label{thm:euler}
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\end{theorem}

\begin{rtheorem}{thm:euler}[Euler's identity revisited]
$e^{i\pi} = -1$
\end{rtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]